# Angular Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading, angular-ngmodel

I have **products-list.component.html** template  and template using ***ngFor** directive. I use **CommonModule** in **products-list.module.ts** and I use **BrowserModule**  once in **app.module.ts**
and  triple checked ***ngFor** usage if it's true. Still giving  "Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div' (used in the 'ProductsListComponent' component template)" error. The problem started when I tried to add lazy loading to my app

**products-list.component.html**

```html
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<div class="products-list">
    <h3 class="products-list__header">Products</h3>
    <div class="products-list__products">
        <div class="product-card" *ngFor="let product of products">
            <a (click)="goToProductDetails(product.id)" >
                <img class="product-card__img" [src]="product.image | safePipe" />
                <div class="product-card__price">$ {{product.price}}</div>
                <div class="product-card__name">{{product.name}}</div>
                <button (click)="addToCart($event, product)"class="product-card__button" type="button">Add To Cart</button>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**products-list.module.ts**

```
import { SafepipeModule } from './../../safepipe/safepipe.module';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NavbarModule } from 'src/app/components/navbar/navbar.module';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ProductsListRoutingModule } from './products-list-routing.module';
import { ProductsListComponent } from './products-list.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [ProductsListComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ProductsListRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NavbarModule,
    
    
  ]
  ,exports:[ProductsListComponent]
})
export class ProductsListModule { }
```

Comment: Is the error only on the editor or the compiling process breaks too? Can you create a Stackblitz example?

Comment: Maybe you have to add your ProductsListModule into your app.module.ts modules.

Comment: I found the solution.  I changed  import status of products-list component in app-routing.module.ts. I wasn't lazily importing products-list component and when I did, it fixed @Rajat@RicardoMachado

Answer (score -1):

use *ngFor
for iterating the array of object or array data